# Neep help for looping through a particular json data format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have some json data that looks like this

```
{"errors":{"toDate":["Date error_message"],"name":["name error_message"]}}

 OR

{"success":{"toDate":["Date update_data"],"name":["name update_data"]}}
```

How can I loop through this using jQuery, javascript!

The json data is returned from server on ajax request!

So I need to display the errors if json {"errors":....}

OR to update a table row if respond is success if json {"success":...}

This is my ajax call function

```
jQuery('#juiDialog').on('submit','#formn-update',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
                jQuery.ajax({
                                Type:'json',
                            global : false,
                            async : false,
                            cache : false,
                            type : 'POST',
                            url : jQuery(this).attr('action'),
                            data:jQuery(this).serialize()
                        }).success(function(data) {                         
                            alert(data.errors.toDate[0]);
                             });
                   });
```

I tried the solution from @Barmar but I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined

SOLVED ::

I forgot to set the dataType in ajax function!!!
dataType:json

Comment: Do those arrays always have just one element?

Comment: @Barmar Yes only one element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery.ajax({
    global: false,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json', // Tell jQuery to parse the JSON result
    url: jQuery(this).attr('action'),
    data: jQuery(this).serialize()
}).success(function (data) {
    if (data.errors) {
        alert(data.errors.toDate[0]);
    } else {
        // do something with data.success.toDate[0] and data.success.name[0]
    }
});
```

Comment: I get the following error:  -- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined

Comment: Did you replace `result` with the name of your variable that contains the parsed JSON? You should use `dataType: 'json'` in your AJAX call so that jQuery will parse it automatically for you.

Comment: SOLVED ::

I forgot to set the dataType in ajax function!!! dataType:json   THANKS for your help!!

Comment: I've updated my answer to fit in with your AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

Here example how you can loop the json object

```
var x = {"success":{"toDate":["Date update_data"],"name":["name update_data"]}}
for(key in x){
   console.log(x[key].toDate);
}
```